# Simulate click event on mobile device

Tags: javascript

I have a click event on window load like so :

```
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById('myEl').click(); // works on desktop, not on mobile
}

window.onload = myFunction;
```

As mentioned, this works on desktop but not on mobile devices. I gathered it was down to mobile handling click events differently. Is that correct ?

I need my element to be 'clicked' on load on all devices, desktop and touch pads (mobiles etc).

Comment: Did you try `.trigger("click")`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah just implemented that, works on desktop, not on mobile :/

Comment: @PraveenKumar is window.onload the correct way to start a function on load on mobile devices too do you know ?

Comment: Is it OK if you get the solution using `jQuery` ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy That's right... Nothing wrong in it.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya jquery should be fine to select the element, but I need to use javascript for the onload as JQuery isn't loaded before I have this snippet

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for mobile Safari. Any help with this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myEl").trigger('click');
    $("#myEl").trigger('touchstart');
}
window.onload = myFunction;
```

For touch event, visit below link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart

Comment: That's the one, great. Thanks for the help :)