# javascript - Simulate a click event (tap with finger) on a button in iOS

Tags: javascript, click, touch

I'm trying to write a script that adds an item to the cart by simulating a click on the add-to-cart button on a webpage

```
<span id="cart-update">
<span class="cart-button">add to basket</span>
</span>
```

When I try to do the following on desktop, it works perfectly

```
document.getElementById('cart-update').click();
```

But when I try doing the same thing on iPhone it doesn't work.
I tried using the advice from this answer ([Simulate click event on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614726/simulate-click-event-on-mobile-device?rq=1))  and it didn't seem to work.
Can you help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "on iphone"? Is it a web page rendered in a browser on an iphone, or is it an IOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried monitoring touch events at all, instead of click events? Mobile browsers have their own events they're monitoring, some not considering "click" as an event at all

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

```
function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  console.log("initialized.");
}
```

A way to work around it would be for a click/touch event to trigger a separate function entirely, like calling handleStart() in your function triggering the click event.
Might be a better separation of concerns, too.